# I want to write a Web Api based client that will consume the social media API using OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

What is the project and requirement?

I have clients - say around 200 - and they want that to implement social login on their website so that their users can login using social media accounts like Facebook and Twitter and others.

My clients don't want to be involved in complex flow of OAuth. I have offered them a service. My client will simply request to my service name "Social Connector" with post back URL (where I can post XML data back to them). I will fetch all data on user behalf and then convert it to XML document and send back using post back URL.

I have been able to successfully implement an ASP.NET MVC 5 web based client that will consume the API from different social media providers like Facebook, Twitter, Google+ using OAuth 2.0.

Consider the following things

- I have to redirect user to autorization page where user can enter his credential
- Then social media send code back to redirect URL
- Get access token and then get user profile
- Process data from social media and make an XML document(specific requirement by boss)
- Post xml document and redirect user back using post back URL in same request(done by form post and auto form submit on body load)
- Show error page in case of any error

But my boss says that we need to have a Web API based client that will do the same.

My questions are:

- Is it good practice to use web API based client for social sites using Oath 2.0?
- Should I continue with the ASP.NET MVC web based client?
- Can I do this all using Web API client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, using OAuth2 to get a user's profile from social media services is a specific protocol named OIDC: OpenID Connect.** It uses OAuth2 to let the user authorize your service to access profile informations from the social media. So, OIDC is an extension of OAuth2.

With OIDC, there are two roles:

- the IDP (Identity Provider): has informations about user's profile
- the RP (Relying Party): wants to get authorization from the user to access his profile from the IDP

So, your service is a relay:

- from your customer point of view, you service acts as an IDP, with your own simple protocol (posting back an XML doc, instead of using some complex JSON web tokens like OIDC IDPs do)
- from the social media point of view, you service acts as a RP

What you did is exactly what FranceConnect does: [FranceConnect](https://franceconnect.gouv.fr/) is a french public service, that acts as an IDP in front of its customers (french public services, for health insurance for instance) and a RP in front of french public identity providers (some public administrations, like the public department of finances).

> Is it good practice to use web API based client for social sites using OAuth 2.0?

What you want to do can be done with your web mechanism (posting XML back to your customer) or with an API. Both can be done and both have been done:

- FranceConnect is doing that only with web mechanism
- [KIF-IdP](https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/france-connect) is another implementation of OIDC that acts as a relay like yours, but doing that with an API based on web services for instance.

So, your mechanism and what your boss asks you to do are both implemented. So, both can be done.

> Should I continue with the ASP.NET MVC web based client?

You should look at some OIDC libraries, since it would be easier to do than using only the sub-protocol OAuth2.0 and implementing a specific way to get the profile with each social media server. Getting the profile is a standard method with OIDC, it does not depend on the social media.

> Can I do this all using Web API client?

Yes. Both can be done.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre Fenyo your answer helped me a lot.